# Node js Flash message

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a better way to do req.flash messages? Like a function that add all the flash messages to one object?

```
app.get('/forgot', function(req, res) {
    var info = req.flash('info'),
        error = req.flash('error'),
        success = req.flash('success'),
        user = req.user;

    var send = {};
        send.user = user;
        send.messages = {
           info: info,
           error: error,
           success: success
        }
    res.render('forgot', send);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just make that a function abstracted? Then it becomes what you want

Comment: Yes it is a good question :)
But I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so to speak.
But if I have to do it. Is there any way to go through all falsh messages dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Well i made my own script.

helper.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
    return function(){
        var buf = '',
            messages = req.flash(),
            types = Object.keys(messages);

        for(var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i){
            var type = types[i],
                msgs = messages[type];

            for(var j = 0; j < msgs.length; ++j){
                buf += '<div class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissable"><a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>' + msgs[j] + '</div>';
            }
        }
        return buf;
    }
};
```

server.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = require('./config/helpers.js')(req, res);
    next();
});
```

index.jade

```
!= messages()
```